# How to clean my url with the help of .htaccess file by removing query string and making url clean ?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have URL like this I want to clean my URL from

http://www.125books.com/move-other-bk?file=Advanced.C%20sharp%20.Programming.pdf

to

http://www.125books.com/move-other-bk/file/Advanced.C%20sharp%20.Programming.pdf

bellow is my htaccess file

> ```
> Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /
> ## hide .php extension snippet
>
> # To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
> RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
>
>
> # To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
> RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Have your code like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(move-other-bk)\?(file)=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^(move-other-bk)/(file)/([^/.]+)/?$ /$1?$2=$3 [L,QSA,NC]

## hide .php extension snippet
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: sir on localhost it give "object not found" 404 Error and on my romote  server it does not load css and some time it remian on search page  ..it changes the url as required but following problems also arises...kindly help me

Comment: sir it move the url to required one but css does not load and the links does not work properly ..for example  www.125books.com/search-bk becomes   www.125books.com/search-bk/move-other-bk

Comment: OK make sure to use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.